# Recovering emails and attachments from an OWA account

Tags: microsoft-outlook, outlook-web-access

I wish to recover emails and attachments from an OWA account and store
them on my computer, without using an email client on my computer.
It appears that Microsoft does not allow this, but would this be a solution :-

https://www.techwalla.com/articles/archive-emails-outlook-access

Comment: What happened when you tried it? I can't even find a 'File' menu in my OWA

Comment: My OWA account is being deleted very soon, so I don't think I can archive the OWA emails as suggested in the above link. I need very urgent help with this problem. It now appears to me that I will need to set up an email client on my computer after all. If I download Outlook onto my computer and open an account, can I transfer the emails and attachments already in my OWA account to the new Outlook account on my computer. If so, how can I do that, please ?

Comment: If you can connect outlook to your OWA account you should be able to archive everything to a PST folder. There are also settings that involve downloading and/or deleting from server usually (offline copy). Is there a free version of outlook? (outlook express?)

Comment: No you cannot. Outlook Web App is purely meant to send and receive email, but does not have a backup function.

If you want to backup email to an external medium, you will need a client such as Microsoft Outlook that supports this.